# The page gets stuck when run the offical demo

Tags: python, 3d, pybullet

I'm new to pybullet, but now I meet some problems after i installed the pybullet and run the demo.
The window always gets stuck and no respond when run the offical demo `python -m pybullet_envs.examples.enjoy_TF_HumanoidBulletEnv_v0_2017may`, which can't load correctly and occur the error message. And wait a few seconds, the window get no respond. I have to close it. Then terminal doesn't show bug or error message.

So can anyone tell me how to solve this or know why it happens? Thank you.

```
[run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1bNG.png)
[stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk8pj.png)
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pefa2.png)
```

sorry, the picture seems can't show.

The methods I tried below:

1. reinstall the pybullet twice
2. install the cmake may because this issue
3. install the tensorflow
4. use official demo and other personal demos